# FTP access control based on users

Tags: ftp

I need a specific feature. I have a ftp site. I want to give full access to some users (Read/Write) and for other users  limited access only(Read). How to do it?. I can control this one through Folder access settings, but it will be applied for all users :-(. I am using bluehost as my server.

When I went through SO I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077024/2288789) . It says we can't have any user management system. Is it true?

Comment: What OS is running on the system that you want to limit access on, and what kind of access do you personally have on that?

Comment: I am using windows OS and using Bluehost as my FTP server. It doesn't differentiate the access level based on the user account. Folder level we can set Read/Write for all users